# How to create a build system in sublime which uses a directory with a space?

Tags: c++, json, mingw, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am trying to create a build system for building C++ files in Sublime Text 3. I have installed MinGW and have correctly set the environment path.

I have created a build system as:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}\\${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
    "shell": "true",
    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["start", "cmd.exe", "@cmd", "/k", "${file_path}\\${file_base_name}"]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, since the directory which contains the C++ file has a whitespace in it (C:\Users\Bryan Adams PC\Documents\C++), when I try to build the file, it says *'C:\Users\Bryan' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

What changes should I make to the build in order to be able to use this directory?
I've tried adding double quotes around the filepaths as \". However it does not work. I have no idea about JSON.

Comment: Is it the `Run` variant that doesn't work? The compile command seems like it should work fine as is.

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to create a new build for C++. Is the built in one not okay for some reason?